# Display image intent rebuilds cache

Tags: android

When I create an intent and pass it a URI of the path of the image on the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital), like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

The image displays after about 15 seconds, because the image viewer has to rebuild its image cache. It says in the debugger

> Unable to read the index file sdcard/Android/data/com.cooliris.media/cache/picasa-thumbsindex.

I'm 99% sure this is a permissions issue, it cannot access its cache file. How do I fix this?